# How to create and extract new_field based on match [msg]

Tags: logstash-grok

hi all i use grok filtering and its all match. This part is ok. My concern is how to extract some data inside `%{GREEDYDATA:msg}` and create it as a field ?

Example of `greddydata:msg` is like given below

A B: C

I used `%{WORD:a}` to test but unfortunately this tag just only able to read the A word and totally ignore B: C

how to convert this A B: C to become one field ? 
Any help is appreciated !

Comment: %{GREEDYDATA:msg} will give you A B: C as a field !!! what else you need to do ?

Comment: Yes it will create only one filed which is name as msg and contains all the messages contet inside. For example one msg field was succesfully created like this msg = i am human and i feel so happy today: true So in my case i want to create *happy today: true* as one field. is it possible ?

Comment: how to determine how many words come before the `:` ?

Comment: basically it will be in coma seperated data..like **...,i feel so happy: true** it will always came like this after coma symbols. so basically 4 words before :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regarding your comment,you can use this:

```
%{GREEDYDATA},%{GREEDYDATA:my_value}
```

tested on:

```
i am human and,i feel so happy today: true
```

result:

```
my_value : i·feel·so·happy·today:·true
```

Comment: Hi @LinPy Thanks and really appreciated! Now i have to think about how about if the value is false